# Binding a dragging image with mouse pointer

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, dom-events

I want to implement such a functionality that while in mousedown the cursor crosses certain boundary, a dragging image binds with the cursor and on mouseup, the ondrop event occurs. How can I implement such a functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done by adding an img element with the mouse pointer.